# Python Tkinter multiple entries get

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to create sudoku(6x6) with GUI (Tkinter) and i made 36 entries with for loop. How can i retrieve numbers from all entries??
With my code i only get number from last entry

## python 3

```
class Window(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master      


    self.Bstart = Button(top, text="CHECK", command=self.check)
    self.Bstart.pack()
    self.Bstart.place(x=500, y=200)

    for g in [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150]:
        for i in [0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200]:

         self.E = Entry(top, width=3)
         self.E.place(x=100+i, y=300+g)

    def check(self):
  
        av = self.E.get()
        self.enjoy.configure(text=av)


top = Tk()
top.geometry('800x800')
app = Window(top)

top.mainloop()

I am thinking about giving different name for self.E 
every time when looping: 

self.E{0} = Entry(top, width=3).format(g+i)
self.E.place(x=100+i, y=300+g)

But of course it does not work.
```

Comment: You are overwriting `self.E` in every loop. Maybe you want to try a list of entries instead?

Comment: With list i am going to need 36 entries which is quite a lot. In the future (sudoku 9x9) i`ll need 81 entry.

Comment: a list with 91 references to widgets is tiny. The widgets themselves take up more more memory than the list used to track them.